# How to read a file stored in adls gen 2 using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to read a parquet file through pandas in databricks notebook. The cluster has permission to access adls.

```
import pandas as pd 
pdf = pd.read_parquet("abfss://abc.parquet")
```

But pandas is not able to read it and throws the below error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2342282971496650> in <module>
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 parquet_file = 'abfss://abc.parquet'
  ----> 3 pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)

  /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py in read_parquet(path, engine, columns, use_nullable_dtypes, **kwargs)
457     """
458     impl = get_engine(engine)
--> 459     return impl.read(
460         path, columns=columns, use_nullable_dtypes=use_nullable_dtypes, **kwargs
461     )

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py in read(self, path, columns, use_nullable_dtypes, storage_options, **kwargs)
212                 )
213 
--> 214         path_or_handle, handles, kwargs["filesystem"] = _get_path_or_handle(
215             path,
216             kwargs.pop("filesystem", None),

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py in _get_path_or_handle(path, fs, storage_options, mode, is_dir)
 64         fsspec = import_optional_dependency("fsspec")
 65 
 ---> 66         fs, path_or_handle = fsspec.core.url_to_fs(
 67             path_or_handle, **(storage_options or {})
 68         )

 /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in url_to_fs(url, **kwargs)
369     else:
370         protocol = split_protocol(url)[0]
--> 371         cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)
372 
373         options = cls._get_kwargs_from_urls(url)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py in get_filesystem_class(protocol)
206     if protocol not in registry:
207         if protocol not in known_implementations:
--> 208             raise ValueError("Protocol not known: %s" % protocol)
209         bit = known_implementations[protocol]
210         try:

ValueError: Protocol not known: abfss
```

I tried a workaround to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps 
pdf = ps.read_parquet("abfss://abc.parquet").to_pandas()
```

The above query actually takes a lot of time in converting the pyspark.pandas dataframe to pandas dataframe.

NOTE: I cannot mount the adls to dbfs because dbfs is disabled by the platform team and hence all the operations need to be done on adls.

I am looking for a faster way or a simpler way to read files from adls gen2 using python pandas.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you post a question about an error, it would be nice to know what the error is

Comment: Updated with the error @Erfan

Comment: How big is the file you're planning to read?

Comment: can you try protocol "adlfs" instead of "abfss", and maybe also `pip install adlfs`

Comment: I did "pip install adlfs" which got installed, and then replaced abfss with adlfs, now it says "Protocol not known: adlfs"

Comment: @AlexOtt file size is variable, will be mostly in the range of 5 MB - 10 MB

Comment: Can you try checking if the operations you are trying to perform using pandas is already available as part of pyspark.pandas ? it seems to have most of the pandas features available. Alternatively if it is allowed copy the file from abfss to your dbfs path and then use pandas there. Be sure to check on the security issues if any and remember to cleanup dbfs after use.

Comment: @rainingdistros, actually there are still many functions not directly available in pyspark.pandas and it will involve lot of rework to replace pandas in the codebase. Due to security issues dbfs has been disabled by the platform team in production currently and they want us to use adls for all operations

Comment: What if I use a single node cluster in databricks? Will it help decrease the conversion time from pyspark.pandas dataframe to pandas dataframe?

Comment: mmm maybe while the job is running have a look at the ganglia chart to monitor where the bottleneck is ?? Check if it is memory related or CPU related (as you said not using all the nodes) and then decide on using a single cluster or just a cluster with a higher configuration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem is resolved, and now I am able to read the data in adls using pandas library. No need of spark or koalas conversion.

```
pd.read_parquet("file_path", storage_options = "")
```

Follow this article, for storage_options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool

Comment: The link goes to some code on MSDN that is related to Synapse, not Databricks.  In fact, I would test the code since its syntax is suspect.

Comment: This will work in databricks as well because I have ran the command just don't forget to pass the right credentials in storage option. Also install adlfs before reading the file from adls

Answer (score 1):

Databricks released pandas on spark.  This replaces the prior koalas library.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html

A search of the documentation shows how to read a parquet file.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.read_parquet.html

Let's assume that all things are equal, is there more overhead using pandas vs spark dataframes.  Yes, I have used the libraries in the past when there were functions that I wanted to use that were only in a pandas dataframe, not a pyspark sql dataframe.

[image]

I have some existing parquet files from the adventures database (SQL Server) that were saved in the data lake as parquet files.

[image]

The pandas code takes 0.84 seconds to return.  We can see the type is pyspark.pandas.frame.Dataframe.

[image]

The native spark code takes 0.66 seconds to return.  We can see the type is pyspark.sql.dataframe.Dataframe.

To recap, the idea that pandas would be faster is probably not true.  The code is almost the same in design.  These files are small.  I wonder what the timings would be for larger files ...

Comment: There are some things that I guess you missed in the question, first I was looking for a solution to read data from adls using pandas, second, we cannot mount adls to dbfs, I cannot use pyspark.pandas because there are still lot of rework required if I choose to go with pyspark because the existing codebase is written purely in pandas. For eg, pd.DateOffset and pd.TimeDelta are not directly usable in pyspark.pandas

Comment: I missed the comment about can not mount ADLS.  If you use native pandas, you might as well as create a single node cluster with larger cpu/memory.  It is not worker node aware.  Therefore, it will only run at the executor node - no distributed processing.  Pandas does not understand ADLS pathing.  That is why it fails.  Pyspark.Pandas does understand Fully Qualified Naming (url) since it was re-written by databricks to be cloud aware.  Suggestion 1 - get the mounted storage restriction lifted and use existing code.  2 - re-write code using pyspark or pyspark.pandas.

Comment: One more comment, if you are going to stick with pandas look at turning on apache arrow.  This in memory format speeds up execution times.  See video from friend Bryan Cafferky.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H00Y9JTcFio (lesson 27)

Comment: Thanks for your input. We will eventually move to spark only but it will take some time. For the time being pd.read_parquet("file_path", storage_options = "") has worked for us to read the data from adls using pandas. I will also look at arrow as you suggested. Thanks again